# How can Use custom input field in functions.php page?

Tags: customization, custom-field, hooks, actions

I have if clause to add action in functions.php page. But I want to give condition value from dashboard as a custom input instead of defining it functions.php. When I am trying 'echo get_field('input_field')' its not working. I have ACF plugin installed

```
if( strpos($url, 'echo get_field('input_field')' === FALSE ){
 add_action( 'init', 'addedactionname' );
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. What exactly are you trying to do? What's the URL here? Are you trying to test the value of `get_field('input_field')`? Or are you actually expecting that string to be in the URL? (I'd guess not) Is this valid on all pages, i.e. do all of your pages have their own input_field?

Comment: And where exactly is this code? If it's at the top level of the plugin then you're probably too early to call get_field() anyway. You should probably move that check inside the action handler.

Comment: I am actually trying to check whether the "randomword" is present in url or not. If present on url then do nothing else add action

if( strpos($url, 'randomword')' === FALSE ){
 add_action( 'init', 'addedactionname' );
}